# Calculation time differs between segmented loops and one whole loop

Tags: random, date-and-time, simulation, timing

I stumbled on a strange issue while simulating a large number of random values, $10^8$ to be precise.

I generated the numbers at first by the following code:

```
\[Alpha]=0.2; 
levytab2 = {};
While[Length[levytab2] < 10^8,
 Clear[u1, u2];
 u1 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
 u2 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
 AppendTo[
  levytab2, (1/Abs[Log[u1]]*(
    Sin[(1 - \[Alpha])*Pi*u2]*(Sin[\[Alpha]*Pi*u2])^(\[Alpha]/(
     1 - \[Alpha])))/(Sin[Pi*u2])^(1/(1 - \[Alpha])))^((
  1 - \[Alpha])/\[Alpha])]
 ];
```

This took two days to calculate up to 6 000 000 numbers.. this is riddiculous. I tested the code with sizes of $10^3$, $10^4$ and $10^5$ and found that their calculation time does not scale by 10 as the sizes do. I then tried to just do a smaller sample size 10 times. This indeed produced calculation times scaling by 10, like the sample size.

For example, simulating $10^4$ numbers took 0.390625 seconds. Simulating $10^5$ numbers took 18.62500 seconds. This is not 10*time-to-simulate-$10^4$ numbers. However, simulating 10 times the $10^4$ points took 3.56 seconds - much more in lines with what is expected.

I then simulated $10^8$ numbers by nesting Do loops of size 10, in the spirit of:

```
Do[
  levytabcbind2 = {};
  Do[
    levytab2 = {};
    While[Length[levytab2] < 10^4,
     Clear[u1, u2];
     u1 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
     u2 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]];
     AppendTo[
      levytab2, (1/Abs[Log[u1]]*(
        Sin[(1 - \[Alpha])*Pi*u2]*(Sin[\[Alpha]*Pi*u2])^(\[Alpha]/(
         1 - \[Alpha])))/(Sin[Pi*u2])^(1/(1 - \[Alpha])))^((
      1 - \[Alpha])/\[Alpha])]
     ];
    Clear[dummy];
    dummy = i;
    AppendTo[levytabcbind, levytab2], {i, 1, 10}]
   Clear[dummy2];
  dummy2 = j;
  AppendTo[levytabcbind2, levytabcbind], {j, 1, 10}];
```

In the end, it took an hour to simulate the $10^8$ points, as the base While loop takes only about 3.5 seconds.

My question is: why does Mathematica take exponentially longer to work through a Do loop of larger size, while doing the same number of calculations in smaller nested Do loops takes the expected time, given sample size growing by 10?

Comment: Because you are repeatedly doing `AppendTo`, the worst way of accumulating lists in Mathematica. If you want a list of things, use `Table`.

Comment: Aha, but do you know of a simpe way of explaining why the blow-up of calculation time? Or is it too technical? 
Also: Could Mathematica handle better then a Table[] command of the same variate? Im wondering how to reset the random variates u1 and u2 inside of it...

Comment: Yes, the reason is that Mathematica cannot predict what you are going to add to the list next; a datum of the same type as the ones already there (ints, doubles, chars) or something completely different like a Word document, PDF, or an image. Hence, it must reallocate on each append, forcing a copy of the existing list. This is scales horribly because each time you append, a longer and longer list must be copied.

Comment: Generate all the random variates right from the start: `u1 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0,1}], 10^6]` and you have one million values, and similarly for `u2`. Then simply apply your function to these lists, because all your operations (`Sin`, `Log` etc.) are listable, so they will thread over `u1` and `u2` automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
u1 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 10^8];
u2 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 10^8];
alpha = 0.2;
ans = (1/Abs[Log[u1]]*(Sin[(1 - alpha)*Pi*u2]*(Sin[alpha*Pi*u2])^(alpha/(1 - alpha)))/(Sin[Pi*u2])^(1/(1 - alpha)))^((1 - alpha)/alpha);
```

The whole thing takes 23 seconds on my computer.

Comment: This makes me feel very dumb and thankful. Luckly my calculatons already work, but thanks for the insight! Will be much more effective on the next runs. Thank you

Comment: It was like that for me when I started using Mathematica, coming from compiled languages where `AppendTo`-like things tend to be constant-time. A good rule of thumb in Mathematica is to use as few loops as possible (`For`, `Do`, `While` etc.)